# possible outcomes for a List

Tags: python

I have possible points `[0,1,2]`. how can I list all the possible ways to create scores 0-10 from the sample list out of 5 turns

ex:

```
score 0: score 0,0,0,0,0
score 1: score 00001, 00010, 00100, 01000, 10000 ....
...
...
```

Not really sure how to approach this problem

I think this is a permutation problem where I generate the permutations of 5 numbers using set 0, 1 ,2

Comment: create scores 0 - 10?  why 10?

Comment: because 2,2,2,2,2 adds up to 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *think* you want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
print list(itertools.product([0, 1, 2], repeat=5))
```